# Namespaced classes not found

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony4, psr-4

In Symfony4 projects, I'd like to autoload classes defined in the `src` folder but whose namespace does not start with `App`. Let's say it starts with `Acme` instead.

I was expecting that the following configuration in `composer.json` to work, but it doesn't and I'm getting class not found exceptions:

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Acme\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump`?

Comment: Yes, I did `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: I have ran into this before.  For some reason Acme\MyAcme always gets changed to App\MyAcme.  Moving your Acme classes into their own directory such as srcAcme works.  Never understood this behavior.  But life is short.

Comment: Why do you need such logic anyway? "classmap" is solution for non-PSR naming. After you standardize your namespaces, you can switch to PSR4 autoloading

Comment: Hah.  I finally remembered what I figured out quite some time ago.  The problem is actually with autowire scanning all files and trying to make services out of them.  The App portion of services.yaml indicates that all files under it are part of the App namespace.  Exclude your Acme classes or move them to a different directory under src and tweak the resource section and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

I have no proof, but I don't think you can use the same namespace in the same directory.

There might be `App\SomeClass`  and `Acme\SomeClass` and composer would look for both of them in `src/SomeClass.php`.

You can use `classmap` autoload for non-standard naming. You should have `App\` in `/src`, so it should be like:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\": "src"
        },
        "classmap": "src"
    }
}
```

But **I recommend having PSR-4 paths standard everywhere**, to prevent such WTFs. In your case renaming `Acme` to `App`.

Comment: Will try, thank you. Note that the idea came to me while reading this thread response: https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/93#issuecomment-305722625. I supposed that it would work since no one shouted on the thread! XD

Comment: It is not a composer/autoload issue.  Something in Symfony actually changes the namespace.  Don't know how.  php itself is fine with multiple namespaces in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

for me, this is working

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Nice edit and that is the way things used to work but not for S4.  Make a quick test case and try it.